# What is wrong with my code? Combining Operators

Tags: python

I have been working on this for hours but I couldn't get it to work correctly. My code is below.

I need to write a code using boolean variables. The code should print `True` if hungry is `True`, and either `coworkers_going` is `True` or `brought_lunch` is `False`.

Here is my code:

```
hungry = True
coworkers_going = False
brought_lunch = False

print(((hungry) and  coworkers_going) or  brought_lunch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "either coworkers_going is True or brought_lunch is False" is considered together and the `or` operator has a lower precedence than the `and` operator, you should use parentheses to group the two expressions so that the `or` operation is evaluated before the `and` operation. Also, use the `not` operator to return `True` when an expression is `False`:

```
hungry and (coworkers_going or not brought_lunch)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to print `True` if `hungry == True` and at the same time `coworkers_going == True` or `brought_lunch == False`, it would be like this:

```py
print((hungry and (coworkers_going or not brought_lunch)))
```